# C++: Use virtual in every class in the inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class FooA {
    public:
    virtual void meth () {cout << "hiA\n";}
};
class FooB : public FooA{
    public:
    void meth () {cout << "hiB\n";}
};
class FooC : public FooB {
    public:
    void meth () {cout << "hiC\n";}
};

int main() {
    FooA a;
    a.meth();
    FooB b;
    b.meth();
    FooC c;
    c.meth();
    FooA* ptr = &a;
    ptr->meth();
    ptr = &b;
    ptr->meth();
    ptr = &c;
    ptr->meth();
    FooB* ptrB = &b;
    ptrB->meth();
    ptrB = &c;
    ptrB->meth();
}
```

The output is this:

```
hiA
hiB
hiC
hiA
hiB
hiC
hiB
hiC
```

The code is basic and self-explanatory. I tried different combinations of making meth() in each class virtual or not. This will change how the output, obviously, especially if FooA::meth() is not declared as virtual. I have come to the conclusion that it is probably best and most clear to just make every instance of that method virtual. Is there any reason not to?

Edit:
I have another question. When you declare a class, and then define it outside of the class declaration, using ::

Like this

```
class Foo{
public:
virtual void bar();
};

void Foo::bar {
cout << "Hello";
}
```

Why can't I do something like

```
virtual void Foo::bar {
cout << "Hello";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any reason not to?

It's superfluous.

If you have a method in a base class declared as `virtual`, this virtuality will be "inherited" by the overriding method.

Other than that, maybe for documentation purposes it *might* be acceptable. However, remember that the best virtuals are *private*, employ the [non-virtual interface](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) idiom.

With that done, the "for documentation" reason falls to the ground, since private methods need no public documentation.

Comment: Ha, yes, this example is very contrived, but my professor requires it to be this way (public virtual methods). Thanks for the article though.

Comment: Do private member functions need private documentation? In C++11, though, there's a better way for a function to "self document" that it's overriding a virtual function in its base class, and that's to declare it with `override`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you don't want a derived class to override the implementation of meth() for some reason.

If you think a derived class might need to change the implementation of meth(), make the method virtual.